# How Update a node attribute in xml using Linq query?

Tags: linq

Hai I have An XDocument .All nodes in this document have an attribute UserId. I want to change the value of this attribute 0 to 1. How to do this using Linq query. I used this.

```
MyNewUserPermission.Descendants("menuNode").Single.SetAttributeValue("userId", Me.UserId)
```

It's not Working.Error shows

```
Sequence contains more than one element
```

XmlFile

```
<menuNode url="" title="Register" id="mnuMainRegister" value="true" userId ="0">
      <menuNode url="Company.aspx?Name=Company" title="Company" id="mnuCompany" value="true" userId ="0"/>
      <menuNode url="Company.aspx?Name=User" title="SubCategory" id="mnuSubcategory" value="true" userId ="0"/>
      <menuNode url="Common.aspx?Name=Category" title="Category" id="mnuCategory" value="true" userId ="0"/>
      <menuNode url="Common.aspx?Name=Employee" title="Employee" id="mnuEmployee" value="true" userId ="0"/>
      <menuNode url="Common.aspx?Name=Product" title="Product" id="mnuProduct" value="true" userId ="0"/>
      <menuNode url="Common.aspx?Name=SaleArea" title="SaleArea" id="mnuSaleArea" value="true" userId ="0"/>
      <menuNode url="Common.aspx?Name=SalePlace" title="SalePlace" id="mnuPlace" value="true" userId ="0"/>
    </menuNode>
```

I dont know this can be be done using linq . Other wise just tell whats wrong with my code.

Comment: can you show us the XML document? Or at least the part of it you're trying to update?

Comment: Now tell, i updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your menuNode contain nested menuNodes the Single operation will throw an exception as `MyNewUserPermission.Descendants("menuNode")` will return multiple values and not just one as required by the Single operation.

Try the `.First` operation instead of the `.Single` operation or `MyNewUserPermission.Root.SetAttributeValue("userId", Me.UserId)` if menuNode is the root of the document.

If you want to set all the menuNode elements' attributes (including the nested ones) then loop through all the `MyNewUserPermission.Descendants("menuNode")` elements and set each one's attribute.

Comment: thank you , I am asking without using a loop , can I do the same thing?

Comment: If you want to update each node then you will require a loop. Linq is good for querying but in general updating of more than one item in a collection still requires a loop.